# Is it possible to make pan roasted garbanzo beans creamy in the center?

Tags: beans, chickpeas

I've been messing around pan roasting garbanzo beans recently, and I'm wondering if it's possible to make them creamy in the center and slightly crispy on the outside, like good potato home fries.

I don't have a lot of experience with garbanzos, so I don't even know if this texture is possible to achieve. I'm currently getting somewhat of a chalkier texture than I'd like (using canned beans and pan roasting on medium heat for 10-20 minutes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually serve these as an appetizer, they're so good with a smoky seasoning blend. 
Using canned beans is where your process is falling down. Use fresh beans that you soaked and cooked. The age of the beans are the deciding factor between chalk and cream. I like to use a crock pot and all manner of seasonings.
Other things I've found:

- Slightly overcook the beans. It makes them softer, and therefore creamier.
- Let them drain completely, while still wet dredge with garbanzo flour (or some flour).
- Thoroughly dry them on a flat surface.
- Fry on pretty high heat using as little oil as possible, and not for very long, either.

Another note: 
I usually make two or three large batches of beans every couple of months. I separate the yield out into 1-2 cup servings and freeze them. I have found that beans which were frozen, but not for very long have that delightful creamy center when fried, but not as crisp an exterior.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for! I was curious if fresh would make any difference -- I'll get some and give it a go this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that baking will give you the texture you are looking for.  On the other hand, there are many recipes available for deep fried chickpeas (garbanzos), such as [this one from Martha Stewart](http://www.marthastewart.com/317671/fried-chickpeas), photo from her site:

[image]

The common theme is to drain and dry canned chickpeas, and then deep fry them for about 5 minutes or so.   They can then be dusted with herbs or spices, if you desire.

Of course, you can also use beans that you cook yourself in the traditional manner, then drain, dry and deep fry.

---

I suspect that the longer frying period is intended to make a crunchy snack, but you may wish to experiment with shorter times to get a crispy exterior while retaining the creamy inside.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot. I think the best method would be experimentation here, although I suspect that the gluten/protein/whatever content of garbanzo beans is too different from potatoes to get that kind of texture. Hummus is creamy, but that probably has more to do with the tahini and oil blended in.